Input High Voltage - Electrical Specifications for Microchip PIC24FJ512GU410
I have a question regarding the electrical specifications for the microcontroller I am using in my latest project: Microchip PIC24FJ512GU406.
More specifically, about the input high voltage ratings for this chip.
The datasheet specifies the following:

And this is the input high voltage parameter from the datasheet, on the chapeter 32. Electrical Characteristics:

Now, the pin that I am concerned about is this one (number 64):

And here are the different pin functions and their buffer types:

I programmed my PIC24F for this pin to be a digital input. The intended function of this pin is to read the state of a pushbutton (either not pushed - ditial 0, or pushed - digital 1), via a voltage divider, similar to the following:

Where Vin can take values from 10V to 16.8V.
Now, for my digital input to read properly if the pushbutton is pressed or not, for all the range of voltages, I need to have two resistors like: R1=10k R2=3k9.
With these values, when Vin=16.8V the voltage on PWR_ON will read 4.71V. When Vin=10V the voltage on PWR_ON will read 2.8 V.
This would work ONLY IF the pin on the microcontroller allows voltages up to 5V.

My question is: with this setup (this microcontroller, and this pin configured as a digital input) and considering the information given in the datasheet, will this pin be able to withstand 5V?
Thank you all.

Why not choose a divider that always reaches the required minimum voltage and then simply clamp it with a zener?

It appears that the pin is 5V tolerant. I paste below the relevant diagram from the datasheet of the microcontroller

Pin RE4 is shaded in the diagram and as per note 1, shaded pins are 5V tolerant.
Based on the electrical specifications, what I understand is if analog function is enabled, max should not go beyond VDD. If it is used as digital only, max can be 5.5V.
If you want to use the resistor divider only, another thing to take care of is whether 2.8V is greater than 0.8VDD. i.e., whether VDD<3.5V.
If you are ok to use 2 extra components, here's an idea. You could use a logic MOSFET whose threshold voltage is <<2.8V and VGS rating >= 5.5V or may be use a BJT instead of the MOSFET. With this, you don't need the pin to be 5V tolerant. You could also consider the voltage clamping ideas suggested by others.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Hi @sai, thank you for your comments! I will consider your circuit with one MOSFET, it is actually a good idea. Thanks for the insight.
As I was saying in another command, I will also consider adding a zener to my circuit, Maybe a good option would be to add a 5.6V zener and calculate my resistances so that 5.5V is not exceeded and also the voltage is higher than 2.64V (detection low level).

The datasheet states that pins on PORT E are Digital-ST type buffers, so that means you are in group DI20 in your electrical specifications.
The pin in question has an Analog alternative function (whether you use it or not, it's there).
DI20 indicates that pins with Analog functions have a rating of 0.8Vdd to Vdd. Specifically they state a Vdd limitation and not a 5.5V limit like the digital only pins. Therefore I would conclude that no the pins are not safe to use higher than Vdd.
Use some form of clamping such as a zener diode or even a cheap LDO to limit the voltage to your Vdd level.

Thank you @tom-carpenter for your answer. I will consider adding a zener to my circuit, even though as sai commented, maybe that microcontroller is actually 5.5V-tolerant. Maybe a good option would be to add a 5.6V zener and calculate my resistances so that 5.5V is not exceeded and also the voltage is higher than 2.64V (detection low level).
In any case, thank you for your time and comments! :)
